Why charges gets accumulated at pointy edge of a conductor, why don't they distributed uniformly due to repulsion between them

Consider a conductor which have unsymmetrical shape as shown in the figure. Initially the conductor is neutral. Then I give some external charge to it. I know charge will get distributed on the surface of the conductor.  But why the charge will not distribute uniformly.  Why there is more charge at pointy edge. Should not charges at pointy edge will repel each other and thus charges should be distributed uniformly.
